# Have to click twice to trigger onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I have to click 2 times on my `onclick-button` to trigger it for the first time. After the first 2 clicks, the button works as expected.

Here is my code:

```
var cv3 = document.getElementById("gallerycanvas");
var context03 = cv3.getContext("2d");
var buttonnext = document.getElementById("buttoncanvasnext");

var myImages = [
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_0.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_1.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_2.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_3.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_4.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_5.jpg',
    'Skins/MonkeyKing_6.jpg'
];
var img = document.createElement("img");
var i = 0;
img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i])

img.onload = function() {
    context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    if (i >= myImages.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    buttonnext.onclick = function() {    
        img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i++]);
        context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: please check my updated answer for your second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `++i` instead of `i++`

To feel difference just use both in console alert.

++i (pre) increment **before** using variable

i++ (post) increment **after**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your onclick method.
You are using i++ in the array

```
buttonnext.onclick = function() {
  img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i++]);
  context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Instead, use i++ before setting the image src;

```
buttonnext.onclick = function(){
   i+=1;
   img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i]);
   context03.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `i++` to increase `i`, the value will be returned before the operand is increased.

Change `buttonnext.onclick` function to,

```
buttonnext.onclick = function() {
  i++;
  img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i]);
  context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

And to make image loop work when keep clicking on button, do following changes,

```
img.onload = function() {
    context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    buttonnext.onclick = function() {
       if (i >= myImages.length - 1) {
          i = 0;
       } else {
          i++;
       }
       img.setAttribute('src', myImages[i]);
       context03.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   }
}
```